# Baseviewid when using List.Views.Add in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, view, sharepoint-2013

I'm using C# to modify a view within a photo library across my sharepoint 2013 farm where there are around 600 sites at the moment.

I'm using the method
    olist.Views.Add("AllPictures", strColl, sQuery, 40, true, true,Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Html, false)

and basically I'm trying to recreate the main "All Pictures" view as running a routine to switch this view to a grid has caused this view to no longer display anything. My problem is that once I've deleted the view and run the code above it will create a new All Pictures view that has a baseviewid of 6 so the photos appear as thumbnails rather than a table with the details of the photo. I need to be able to specify the baseviewid as 1 but I've not yet found a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Use code which I found here http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/listviewwebpart-spview-two-sides-of.html in the comments section. I hope Stefan doesn't mind me copying some of it here.

Important to note is that the wp.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper(); line is commented out because otherwise it will use the baseviewid of the current default view which is 6 
which is exactly what we don't want.

The code gets the Photos and Videos list, then gets all the web parts that the list uses, when it gets the AllPictures web part it then saves it for later deletion, adds a new listviewwebpart (but at this stage we can
only add the baseviewid), then deletes the current web part (it seems to only work well in this order) and then gets the hidden view that is created, see stefan's blog for more details.

The second call to Program.UseList then resets some of the view back to how it should look if there is a baseviewid of 1, for this I look at another site with a baseviewid of 1 and checked in sharepoint designer at the XmlDefinition
to see exactly what the xml should look like.

Hope this helps someone else out.

```
     public void LibraryCode(string url)
    {
        Guid hiddenViewGuid = Guid.Empty;
        SPList library = null;
        string listUrl = "Photos1/Forms/AllPictures.aspx";

        Program.UseList(url, listUrl, list =>
        {
            SPFile file = list.ParentWeb.GetFile(listUrl);
            Guid listID = file.ParentFolder.ParentListId;

            if (!listID.Equals(Guid.Empty))
            {
                library = list.ParentWeb.Lists[listID];
                if (library.ForceCheckout && file.Level != SPFileLevel.Checkout) file.CheckOut();
            }

            SPLimitedWebPartManager mngr = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
            SPLimitedWebPartCollection webparts = mngr.WebParts;
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart op = null;
            for (int k = 0; k < webparts.Count; k++)
            {
                //get reference to webpart 
                          op = webparts[k]; 

                          //check webpart Title to find webpart whose value is to be changed 
                          if (op.Title.Equals("AllPictures"))
                          {
                              break;
                           } 
             }

            XsltListViewWebPart wp = new XsltListViewWebPart();
            wp.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
            //comment out the line below or the new view gets the same baseviewid as
            //wp.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
            wp.XmlDefinition = "<View BaseViewID='1'/>";

            mngr.AddWebPart(wp, "Left", 1);
            //remove existing web part otherwise there will be two tables of the data on the same page
            mngr.DeleteWebPart(op);
            hiddenViewGuid = new Guid(wp.ViewGuid);
        });

        Program.UseList(url, listUrl, list =>
        {
            SPView view = list.Views[hiddenViewGuid];
            view.Title = "All Pictures";
            view.Update();

            // load the passed viewSchema in an XmlDocument
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(view.HtmlSchemaXml);

            // set the Name attribute with the ID of the hidden LVP's SPView - we use a simple trick to update the full schema of the hidden view
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            root.SetAttribute("Name", view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper());
            root.SetAttribute("BaseViewID", "1");
            root.SetAttribute("Type", "HTML");
            root.SetAttribute("Hidden", "False");
            // do some changes to the view schema
            XmlElement viewFieldsEl = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ViewFields") as XmlElement;
            if (viewFieldsEl != null) { viewFieldsEl.InnerXml = @"<FieldRef Name=""DocIcon""/>
                <FieldRef Name=""LinkFilename""/>
                <FieldRef Name=""ImageSize""/>
                <FieldRef Name=""FileSizeDisplay""/>
                <FieldRef Name=""Modified""/>
                <FieldRef Name=""RequiredField"" Explicit=""TRUE""/>
                <FieldRef Name=""PreviewOnForm"" Explicit=""TRUE""/>
                <FieldRef Name=""ImageCreateDate""/>
                <FieldRef Name=""Project_x0020_Tags""/>
                <FieldRef Name=""_Comments""/>
                <FieldRef Name=""Originator""/>"; }

            XmlElement javascriptEl = doc.SelectSingleNode("//JSLink") as XmlElement;
            if (javascriptEl != null) { javascriptEl.InnerXml = "clienttemplates.js|callout.js"; }

            // create a dummy view to hold the new schema
            SPView cloneView = new SPView(list, doc);
            // a small trick with reflection so that we can update the dummy view
            typeof(SPView).GetField("m_bExistsInDatabase", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(cloneView, true);

            // this will actually update the hidden SPView associated with the LVP
            cloneView.Update();


            if (library != null)
            {
                SPFile file = list.ParentWeb.GetFile(listUrl);

                if (library.ForceCheckout) file.CheckIn("");
                if (library.EnableMinorVersions) file.Publish("");
                if (library.EnableModeration) file.Approve("");
            }
        });
    }
```